# How to pass form values by http post angular 2

Tags: angular, http, http-post, angular5, angular6

I am trying to pass a value by current url using `POST` http method in angular 2 but I am getting error.

**TS:**

```
  let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
  urlSearchParams.append('arrydetails', this.registerForm.value);

  this.http.post('currenturl', urlSearchParams).subscribe(
  data => {
    alert('ok');
  },
  error => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
  }
)
```

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: Are you using http request or httpClient?

Comment: can you create a stackbliz?

Answer (score 2):

**Angular's documentation on http requests:**

https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Here you will be able to find out to properly make POST, DELETE, PUT requests and how to to pass the value of form fields into the request.

**To provide a snippet of what the Angular doc suggests**

```
addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
       return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
    );
}
```

**Now the solution**

In the example where you would want to place your data to be posted is where 'hero' can be found and in your case it seems you want it to be 'this.registerForm.value'? The way your currently doing the post your not passing any data to be posted.